# Identifying a principle that connects actions with responsibilities

Tags: ethics

Consider the following statement:

> If *x* has **decided to make** an action *A* that caused *B* and *x* was aware that *A* could (with sufficiently high probability) cause *B* **(when (s)he did *A*)**, then *x* is morally responsible for the consequences of *B*. **(This presupposes that *x* had the option to not do *A*.)**

Assuming this ethical principle could, for example, hold Peter responsible for running over a pedestrian while driving drunk. Peter (*x*) did the action of "driving drunk" (*A*) that caused "a pedestrian being run over" (*B*), which means that Peter is morally responsible for *B*, since he knew that *A* could (with sufficiently high probability) cause *B*.

Has a principle similar to this ever been proposed? (Does it have a name?) If so, where can I find literature about it.

#### OP EDIT

It seems that my question was not properly phrased.

First, I'm interested in actions that *x* decided to make and made because of such decision. This also means that he had other options. (I've added the bolds to the statement for clarifying this sense.)

Second, the sense of moral responsibility I'm looking for is the kind that, for example, could make Peter pay some indemnification to the (relatives of the) run-over person.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111879/discussion-on-question-by-lfba-identifying-a-principle-that-connects-actions-wit).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Still, this is a so-called "loaded question", or "complex question" fallacy. From Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question): "A loaded question or complex question is a question that contains a controversial assumption (e.g., a presumption of guilt)."

Comment: You cannot justify something, if it doesn't exist. And moral responsibility for one's past actions simply doesn't.

Comment: I don't see anything controversial here at all. This would be a very typical example of standard legal liability, which seem to be your concern. To speak of "moral responsibility" is another matter requiring a broader framework, but similarly your case seems pretty standard, since you already rule out predetermination, force, ignorance, and impairment. Even Gorgias would have to reach into a deep bag of tricks to see Peter walk.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting your point, @Silk. The responsibility would not be for past actions, but for their consequences. On the other side, what I'm asking is to *identify* if an ethical principle such as this was ever proposed. None of this presupposes that such principle is true. In fact, the answer could refer to works criticising it.

Comment: @lfba -- same point, we are no more responsible for the consequences of our actions than for the actions themselves. There *is* no free will at the time of the action -- it is fully determined by the sum of our experiences at that moment, and nothing else. Many philosophers shared this belief -- I already mentioned Socrates. Spinoza as well, and Descartes probably too. Or, here is a contemporary article, [arguing the same point](https://donaldrobertson.name/2013/03/09/stoic-fatalism-determinism-and-acceptance/).